# What's a reliable way to drain battery on Windows 10 without admin?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

My work laptop has group policy that resets our volume if it's muted, and we don't have permissions to shut down the laptop, only sleep it. The laptop takes itself out of sleep even if it's unplugged. I have a small apartment so I can't keep it far away enough that it doesn't wake me up while I'm sleeping with email notifications. The group policy also resets the audio device so sounds always come out of the built-in speakers if I have headphones plugged in. The only solution I've found is to drain the battery to zero, but this takes a very long time. Is there something I can do on Windows 10, without admin access, to drain the battery very quickly?

I found this question ([Fastest way to drain battery](https://superuser.com/questions/325849/fastest-way-to-drain-battery)) but it seems like the yes command isn't included on Windows.

Comment: I bet you can hold down the powerbutton for 5 seconds to turn it off hard. That is a much better approach than to drain the laptop's battery, which essentially would do the same thing, except keep the power in the device and keep the battery healthy. If it puts it to sleep, press the button to wake it up, and keep holding it until it turns off again.

Comment: I agree with the above.  Close (shut down) ALL apps before forcing a shutdown.  Then contact your employer with the issue.

Comment: Does the laptop have a removable battery pack?

Comment: All of the above are GREAT.. BUT.. have you reached out the IT and told them your problem?  Sometimes you get an a$$, sometimes you get an idiot that doesn't know how to fix it, and sometimes.. you will get someone that actually cares and will fix the GP.  There is probably very little reason to not allow you to mute your machine.  Can you plug in a USB headset and make that the primary sound source?  Even if you can't mute it.. that wouldn't be obnoxious.  If that works, you might even try a "modified" headset that doesn't work. ;)

Comment: Draining the battery completely is quite damaging to it.  Is that part of the intention?  I do not like the idea, but I expect running a cpu burnin/stress test will drain the battery pretty fast. Alternatively I might do some mining of a cryptocurrecy - eg mining monero on a web page if I cant rin programs.

Comment: You have an employer problem more than a technical problem.